# Using value expression in beans xml IntelliJ Warning Cannot resolve property key

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, javabeans

Not sure if the title is saying what I'm really trying to say, I'm not really sure how to describe it. But here is working code(adding substitutes for class names):

```
<bean id="myClassBean"
        class="com.stuff.stuff1.stuff2.MyClassBean">
    <property name="propertyName" value="${foo.bar}"/>
  </bean>
```

In some local-properties.xml we have:

```
<entry key=foo.bar">false</entry>
```

This all runs fine, it get the right value and everything. But for everywhere I use ${some.value} in this file intellij has a warning saying it "Cannot resolve property key" and has a yellow line under the value. The problem is there are hundreds of these so a bunch of useless(maybe not?) warnings.

Is there some way to help IntelliJ know where to look for these properties so that these warnings go away? Obviously there is not issue once everything is built because the code works as expected.

Comment: Did you configure the Spring context with the properties? A sample project would help to understand the problem better: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.